# Can "Avert" be used in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I am listening to an audio; the speaker is not native. He says, "this ideology is more averting more against the cause of freedom".I checked the dictionary but I am still confused. Is this sentence correct or is that a different word because the sound is not very clear. I might have not heard correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence doesn't make sense. Without any relevant context provided the second "more" is totally useless, and avert isn't used in an appropriate way. To avert smth = to prevent it from happening,  to avoid it, (Merriam Webster). One could say "The ideology averts the cause of freedom" (though your answer doesn't provide any context for this sentence, and thus it hasn't got much sense). To avert is not a feature, one object can't be more averting than another.
If you look for "more averting" in a corpus, such as Skells, you'll find zero hits
https://skell.sketchengine.co.uk/run.cgi/concordance?lpos=&query=more+averting

Comment: @pak 79 if the question was useful to you, please mark it! :)